# Weird encoding replacing

Tags: character-encoding

I have a file. I don't know how it was processed. It's probably a double encoding. I've found this link about double encoding that solved almost my problem:

http://www.spamusers.com/encoding.htm

It has all the double encodings substitutions to do like:

```
ÃƒÂ€    À
ÃƒÂ     Á
ÃƒÂ‚    Â
```

Unfortnately I still others weird characters like:

```
ÃÂº
ÃÂ§
ÃÂ¶
```

Do you have an idea on how to clean these weird characters? For the ones I know I've just made a bash script and I've just replaced them. But I don't know how to recognize the others. I'm running on linux so if you have some magic commands I would like that.

Comment: It looks like Japanese SHIFT-JIS. Might be wrong, though.

Comment: There are no magic commands for mistreated encodings. If you know *how* the data has been misinterpreted and mishandled, you may be able to reverse these exact steps to get the original data back, unless it has been irreversible replaced. Are you sure *you're* not just handling the data incorrectly?

Comment: It should be italian, but I don't know.

Comment: No, data are from customers that doesn't know (yeah, I believe it) how they screwed up this thing.

Answer (score 0):

The “double encodings substitutions” page that you link to seems to contain mappings meant to fix character data that has been doubly UTF-8 encoded. Thus, the proper fixing routine would be to reverse such mappings and see if the result makes sense.

For example, if you take A with grave accent, À, U+00C0, and UTF-8 encode it, you get the bytes C3 A0. If these are then mistakenly understood as single-byte encodings according to windows-1252 for example, you get the characters U+00C3 U+00A0 (letter Ã and no-break space). If these are then UTF-8 encoded, you get C3 83 for the former and C2 80 for the latter. If these bytes in turn are interpreted according to windows-1252, you get ÃƒÂ€ as on the page.

But you don’t actually have “ÃƒÂ€”, do you? You have some digital data, bytes, which display that way *if* interpreted according to windows-1252. But that would be a wrong interpretation.

You should first read the data as UTF-8 encoded, decode it to characters, checking that all codes are less than 100 hexadecimal (if not, there’s yet another error involved somewhere), then UTF-9 decode again.